# What does "copywrite" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A pair of mouse ears and a big castle – these are internationally recognized symbols that mean that you are about to watch an incredible movie or are heading to the happiest place on earth. We all know Disney, and many of us have gladly watched many of their films. What makes this company so successful and what can you learn from them when it comes to copywriting? Let’s take a look at this powerful and incredible company for some great copywriting inspiration!
>   What makes this company so successful and what can you learn from them when it comes to copywriting?
>   <sub>Source: https://expresswriters.com/dream-wish-heart-makes-disney-copywriting/</sub>

What does ***copywrite*** mean here? Does it mean writing?

Comment: Please provide what you've found when looking this up in a dictionary and then talk about what is still unclear to you.

Comment: @jim I checked this word, but there was not such a word in the dictionary.

Comment: Did you try looking for the word exactly as it appears in the article? That usually works better than trying to guess the correct root of the word because most online dictionaries will take you to the correct entry even if you search for a different but related form.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's been around a long time. *Copywriter* and *copywriting* emerged in the first decade of the 20th century in contexts in which it is clear that it is an established term of art.

Comment: @StoneyB - of course, it's just that from reading only the OP's paragraph it makes it feel like it was actually using the wrong word - mouse ears, big castles & Disney all spell 'copyright' until you look more closely at what they're actually talking about.

Comment: @Tetsujin It never occurred to me. But then copywriting is what I do for a living, so I suppose it wouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article you mentioned uses only ***copywriting*** and ***copywriter***, but there is NO ***copywrite***. This is very important. Let's begin with what "copywriting" is. According to Wikipedia:

> **[Copywriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copywriting)**
>   *Not to be confused with Copyright.*
>    
>   **Copywriting** is writing copy for the purpose of advertising or marketing. The copy is meant to persuade someone to buy a product, or influence their beliefs.

In case you might be confused by this usage of ***copy***, here is how Macmillan Dictionary defines it:

> **[copy](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/copy)**
>   <sup>noun</sup>
>   3 [uncountable] writing that is ready to be published in a newspaper or magazine
>   ​　　*Copy for our April issue must be submitted by 20th March.*

It is recommended to avoid using *copywrite*. If you want to say what copywriters do, you can say they "write advertising" or they "write copy", as [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/copyright-copywrite/) suggests.

> **Copywrite** is a rarely occurring backformation from *copywriter*—which refers to a writer of copy, especially in advertising. It has never caught on, and some might consider it an error. If you want to say what copywriters do, say not that they copywrite but that they write copy.

Comment: Thanks. so Can I say writhing advertisement?

Comment: or writhing story?

Comment: @user123 Yes, you can say that *They write advertisements*, or more simply *They write ads*. Writing story can mean a lot of things and "ads as stories" will probably not be the first thing that comes to most listeners' mind.

Comment: @user123 -- "Writhing" means "squirming".  "Writing" means "using written or typed words to express an idea."  It is more common to say "ad writing" or "writing ads" or "story writing" or "writing stories" than "writing advertisement" or "writing story".

Comment: It's important to note the Macmillan definition. As a typesetter, what I set was copy, whether it was news, editorial or advertising. Copywriting is not just an advertising and marketing activity, even if most people who would call themselves copywriters (as opposed to newswriters or editorialists, who also write copy) are involved in marketing one way or another.